# Minimum subtree on xml with XDocument

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, spanning-tree

I have xml document that needs to be proceeded using XDocument

```
<elem c="98500000">
    <elem c="98510000">
      <elem c="98511000"/>
      <elem c="98512000"/>
      <elem c="98513000">
        <elem c="98513100"/>
        <elem c="98513200"/>
        <elem c="98513300"/>
        <elem c="98513310"/>
      </elem>
      <elem c="98514000"/>
    </elem>
  </elem>
```

I try to get minimum subtree by selected node attributes e.g. 98512000, 98513300, 98514000 :

```
<elem c="98500000">
    <elem c="98510000">
      <elem c="98512000"/>
      <elem c="98513000">
        <elem c="98513300"/>
      </elem>
      <elem c="98514000"/>
    </elem>
  </elem>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a list of desired `c` values, you can remove elements where `c` attribute value is not in the list and no descendant elements has `c` attribute value in the list :

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse("your XML document string here");
var list = new List<string>(){"98512000", "98513300", "98514000"};
doc.Descendants()
    // all `c` value doesn't match current element's `c` attribute value
   .Where(o => list.All(c => (string)o.Attribute("c") != c) 
                    && 
    // and all descendant elements doesn't have matching `c` attribute value
               o.Descendants().All(d => !list.Any(c => (string)d.Attribute("c") == c)))
   .Remove();
Console.WriteLine(doc.ToString());
```

**<kbd>[`dotnetfiddle demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9OLnvc)</kbd>**

**output :**

```
<elem c="98500000">
  <elem c="98510000">
    <elem c="98512000" />
    <elem c="98513000">
      <elem c="98513300" />
    </elem>
    <elem c="98514000" />
  </elem>
</elem>
```